# How do pivotal shows like Babylon 5 affect their actors?

Tags: babylon-5

I think I've watched Babylon 5 start to finish nearly half a dozen times. The movie has shaped me in my life and is always at the top of my shows to recommend to people to watch, even though it is almost 30 years old now.

Are there specific sources available somewhere on the Internet that I can reference to learn more about how the actors' participation in this show affected their lives? Has it changed them for the better? I haven't found much online about their personal experiences or stories related to being in this series.

Comment: You will probably want to sift through convention panel videos for this type of information, if they exist.

Comment: As written, this is rather too broad to be answered usefully.

Comment: There’s [a whole documentary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_We_Left_Behind) about it!

Comment: That looks like DS9! :( Bummer! Is there one for Babylon 5?